# Node/NPM managing local packages

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-link

**TL;DR** How do I configure different "sub-modules" in a modular `node.js` project to refer to one another as simply as possible?

I'm trying to wrap my head around local packages for NPM, specifically as they relate to a modular project.

I'm building a web app with a front end and a back end API. These need to share a package which exports simple models. My project directory structure looks like this:

```
package
├── api
│   ├── dist
│   │   └── <compiled files>
│   ├── node_modules
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
│       └── <source files>
├── application
│   ├── dist
│   │   └── <compiled files>
│   ├── node_modules
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── package.json
│   └── src
│       └── <source files>
└── models
    ├── dist
    │   └── <compiled files>
    ├── node_modules
    │   └── ...
    ├── package.json
    └── src
        └── <source files>
```

Both the API and application projects are going to use models, so I abstracted that code to a separate sub-module within my project.

I've read the documentation for `npm link` and that seems to be the right approach because, as I understand it, it symlinks the package in the `node_modules` dir. This gives access to the code as it exists right now, instead of installing a copy in `node_modules`. Sounds like what I need, but there is a wrinkle: I'm working on this project from a couple of different places: my laptop, my office at work, and occasionally from home. In addition, others will be contributing to this project in the future.

I would like to make it as simple as possible for a new contributor to get up and running with development.

Currently, a new contributor goes through these steps:

1. clone the repository
2. `cd` into the models dir

   1. run `npm install`
   2. `npm link`
3. `cd` into the api dir

   1. run `npm install`
   2. `npm link models`
4. `cd` into the application dir

   1. run `npm install`
   2. `npm link models`
5. start working

What I would like to do (and I think `npm` *should* be capable of doing) is:

1. clone the repository
2. `cd` into the models dir

   1. run `npm install`
3. `cd` into the api dir

   1. run `npm install`
4. `cd` into the application dir

   1. run `npm install`
5. start working

I could write a script to do this, but it seems like an obvious use case for `npm` and I suspect that it's probably capable of doing something like this. I think I may be overlooking something because I'm not finding it in the documentation.

Comment: Is it really needed to have three separate `package.json`? Shouldn't you only create a main `json` file? I haven't been in a situation where it is a need yet

Comment: Why? NPM already does deduplication for you. If this is one project you don't need three package.json files, just use a single one. On the other hand, if these are three different projects that are independent and can be published each in their own right, then good news: npm will already automatically do link based deduplication for you.

Comment: Re: multiple package.json files - ultimately, this code will be run in multiple docker containers and I was looking for a way to ensure that unnecessary dependencies are installed. For example, if the API container needs a dependency that the application container does not, this seemed like the simplest way to avoid installing it where it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

There may be better ways to solve this, but..

One possibility is to create a `package.json` in the root of your project, which handles all of the initialization of your project.

```
package
├── package.json
```

And the contents of the `package.json` has no dependencies, but scripts to link and install dependencies for all of the submodules using just `npm install` from the `package` directory.

If you put the following in a `package.json` in your `package` folder

```
{
  "name": "package-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Some description",
  "scripts": {
    "init-models": "cd ./models && npm install && npm link",
    "init-api": "cd ./api && npm install && npm link",
    "init-app": "cd ./application && npm install && npm link",
    "postinstall": "npm run init-models && npm run init-api && npm run init-app"
  }
}
```

You will just need to `npm install` to initialize the whole project.